# Round number into DataGridView load from SQLServer C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, format

Hello i develop software with c#, this software load value from sql server database, i have problem with money value read from sql server, for example: in sql server i have save price value with this value:
[image]

but when i load value from sql server and I go inside into datagridview the value It is read as:

[image]

how to take off the decimals in more?

Comment: `Columns["prezzo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";`

Comment: `Columns["prezzo"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";` I think would be preferred since the column displays currency.

Comment: i have try but  nothing changes @shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Set you Format String using CellStyle Builder an set the Custom format to # mm

How to do it :

1 .Right click on Grid, then Properties
2. In the property window, click the button that will popup up the Edit Columns Dialog
3. Select the cell you want to format
4. On the right side of the Edit Columns Dialog select the DefaultCellStyle property Click the DefaultCellStyle property
5. CellStyleBuilder dialog will open Here you have the format property, this will give you the Format String Dialog
6. Set the Custom property to N2 you will see the preview at the bottom
7. Click OK . till you are back to your Grid.

If you want to do it from Code, put this code inside `Form_load` event.

```
yourgridnAME.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: i have try but  nothing changes @Arulkumar